# Ionic + Genymotion : JavaScript logs

Tags: javascript, logging, console, ionic-framework, genymotion

I'm trying to create an app with Ionic on Linux. I use the emulator Genymotion  because ADB doesn't work on my computer (black screen until the end of time). I haven't any problem to run the app on Genymotion with `ionic run android` but I'm wondering how to see the JavaScript logs (I need to check what is wrong with the plugin cordova file). I tried to see it through the browser but it doesn't work.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

1. Set adb to IP of genymontion.
2. Run Chrome
3. enter this url chrome://inspect/#devices
4. Enjoy.

Comment: looks pretty simple :) but how do I get the IP of genymotion (and set adb to this IP) ?

Comment: read faq of genymotion :P https://www.genymotion.com/#!/support?chapter=collapse-adb#faq I did connect vs2013 dont know exacly ionic but should work...

http://ionicframework.com/docs/ionic-cli-faq/#genymotion

Comment: this is what I have in the url http://imgur.com/aeAmNnZ where do I expect console.log to appear?

Comment: in chrome console should be aviable.